# Undefined function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering an error that doesn't seem to make sense. 
Chrome's console is saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: clicked_server is not defined`

I tried almost everything to fix it but the error itself doesn't make much sense

```
<script>
    var selected_char = 'X';

    function draw_list () {
        // lets draw an x in all server in the array
        var server_id = 0;
        var draw_servers = new Array();
        draw_servers = document.getElementById("server_arr").value.split(";");

        foreach(draw_servers as server_id) {
            document.getElementById("server("+server_id+")").innerHTML = selected_char;
        }    
        // Update the counter and servers array
        server_count_field.innerHTML = "Buy Server("+servers_array.length+")";
    }

    function clicked_server(server_id) {
         var clicked = document.getElementById("server("+server_id+")").innerHTML;
         if (clicked == selected_char) remove_server(server_id);
         else add_server(server_id);
    }

    window.onload = draw_list();


    function add_server(server_id) {
        // select a server for purchase
        var servers_array = document.getElementById("server_arr").value;

        if(servers_array.length > 0) servers_array = servers_array + ";" + server;
        else servers_array = server;

        document.getElementById("server_arr").value = servers_array;
    }
</script>
```

My HTML is working perfectly. Here it is

```
<form action="dobuyserver.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="server" id="server_arr"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Buy Server(0)" id="server_count"/>
    </form>

<td style="background-color:##000000;" onclick="clicked_server(9)"><font color="#FFFFFF">
                        <strong>
                        <span id="server(9)">
                        &nbsp;
                        </span>
                        </strong>
                        </font></td>
```

Comment: Try putting the javascript before the HTML in your page.

Comment: The javascript is before the HTML

Comment: Make sure the JavaScript is actually included in the page, too.

Comment: Better to remove inline JS and have it separated... anyway do you have a live link?

Comment: It is actually included as well. I see it perfectly using Chrome's inspect element.

Comment: Are there any errors displayed on the console during the initial load of the page?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, ()s in an id is not [valid html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)(someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @Sam If you're going to use js fiddle, at least [use it correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ8sr/1/).

Comment: @Daedalus In html5, the `id` can have pretty much anything.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thanks for that; interesting to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the stated error is that your javascript fails before getting to your function.

```
foreach(draw_servers as server_id) {
```

This line is invalid, so the js blows up and never goes beyond that line.

Comment: Anyone care to comment on the downvote?  This is the actual answer to the question asked.  The other answers point out an error but not the error that causes the `Uncaught ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding you need to use

```
 window.onload = draw_list;
```

instead of

```
 window.onload = draw_list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `window.onload = draw_list();` with `window.onload = draw_list;`

Answer (score 0):

[window.onload](http://javascript.about.com/library/blonload.htm)

Use `window.onload = draw_list;` instead of `window.onload = draw_list();`